# Proof for uncertainty mixing intuition

Tags: chi-squared-test, covariance, uncertainty

Could somewone give me a mathematical proof for this 'intuitive' result?

I have a random vector $\mathbf{Y}$ related to another random vector $\mathbf{X}$ with the equation $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}$, with $\mathbf{A}$ a (deterministic) symmetric positive-definite matrix. I am interested in the *relative spread* of $\mathbf{Y}$ in comparison with the spread of $\mathbf{X}$. The intuition says that it's going to be more difficult to find too high/small values (or outliers) in $\mathbf{Y}$ components than in in $\mathbf{X}$ components due to the "mixing process of uncertainty", provided that the variables $X_i$ are not perfectly correlated (in that we have the same *relative spread*.

What I've tried is to compute this statistic for each $j$:
$$\chi_j^2=\left(\frac{Y_j-\mathrm{E}[Y_j]}{\sigma(Y_j)}\right)^2$$

After some easy computations we obtain, using Einstein notation and defining $\Sigma_{ij} = \mathrm{COV}(\mathbf{X})$ and the fact that $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric

$$\chi_j^2 = \frac{\left[A_{ij} \sigma(X_i)\frac{X_i - \mathrm{E}[X_i]}{\sigma(X_i)}\right]^2}{A_{ij}\Sigma_{ij}A_{ij}}$$

Nevertheless, I don't know how to continue the proof, if there is any sense to continue it because what I want, definitely, is to relate *some kind* of adimensional uncertainty property of $\mathbf{Y}$ components to the same quantity in $\mathbf{X}$ components.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you imposing some extra assumptions about $\mathbf{A}$ or $\mathbf{X}$? Otherwise, if $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}$, then $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{Y}$, so the situation is symmetric between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "spread" of a random vector, as well as the relationship between "$X_i$" and "$\mathbf{X}$"?

Comment: Juho Kokkala: You are right... it should be another condition and I'm not being aware. In fact, in my problem $\mathbf{A}$ is a flexibility matrix so its components are *big* numbers... but I'm looking for something that doesn't depend on dimensionality. I don't really know how to put it in a mathematical way.

whuber: I don't really know how to define this *spread* in a mathematical way, that's the fact. I defined this $\chi^2$ statistic in order to reflect this *spread*.